# Обработка действия, альтернативное конвертеру изменения изображения при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf, button, конвертер

В программе есть `ListBox`, в элементах которого следующая структура:

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="18" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image ToolTip="Видимость" Margin="5,0,5,0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Image.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=View, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=FactViewConverter} }">
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Image.Style>
            </Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button x:Name="BtnVis" Grid.Column="2" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.FactVisibleCommand, ElementName=lstFacts}"  
                     Style="{StaticResource ButtonFilter }" Margin="0,0,13,0">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image ToolTip="Видимость" Margin="0">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">

                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=VisibleImageConverter} }">
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="../Images/invis.png"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

На кнопке есть изображение, которое меняется с помощью конвертера при нажатии.

Но аналогичное действие, вызываемое нажатием кнопки, происходит и при других действиях (через контекстное меню заголовке столбца таблицы).
Можно ли как-нибудь вызвать изменение изображения кнопки при вызове другого метода?

Comment: Совет на будущее: добавляйте тег используемого языка программирования - `C#`, `F#`,... это привлечет больше внимания к вопросу -> вероятность получить ответ возрастет.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен...лучше создайте MCVE или опишите проблему более подробно.

Comment: Ну, если вам не хочется конвертер, вы можете добавить DataTrigger на нужное условие. Возможно, придётся перенести триггер в стиль, не уверен.